# Is there a way to mirror directory changes in Terminator?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, bashrc, terminator

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and am using Terminator as my primary terminal. I like it because it lets me keep a python interpreter and bash terminal open at the same time, in the same view.

What is annoying is that I end up moving between directories A LOT, and then I have to do it twice. Is there a way to set up a terminator configuration to do that? To have terminator mirror directory changes.

I'm guessing I'm not the only one that finds that frustrating!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok. If I understand correctly, you basically have a [Terminator](https://code.google.com/p/jessies/wiki/Terminator) window in a split view, where the one buffer is a Bash shell and the other is a Python interpreter. Now, whenever you type a command like `cd Pictures/` in the Bash buffer, you want to automatically send the command `os.chdir("Pictures/")` to the Python buffer, so that it changes directories simultaneously with your Bash shell. Kind of like in this image:

[image]

...where the `os.chdir` command in the Python buffer should be entered automatically when you type a `cd` command in the Bash buffer. Right? If yes, here's a...

## Solution

**Step 1: Assign the two buffers to the same group**

Terminator supports groups of windows. We'll assign those two buffers to the same group, in order to later use Terminator's feature of broadcasting commands to windows in the same group. In this example I will assign both buffers to a group named *Tau* (actual name doesn't matter, but make sure it's the same for both buffers).

[image]

**Step 2: Define keyboard shortcuts to switch group broadcasting on and off**

By default Terminator does not have keyboard shortcuts for these, but we need them now, so we'll define them via Terminator's *Preferences* menu. I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to switch group broadcasting on, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to switch it off. You can pick any other keyboard shortcuts you like, though you will have to adapt Step 3 appropriately.

[image]

Now, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>, and whatever you type in the one buffer will appear in the other buffer. By typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> you deactivate that behavior again.

If the Python interpreter understood a command such as `cd Pictures/`, to change a directory in both buffers, all you would have to do now would be something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>`cd Pictures/`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, to broadcast the command *as is*. But the normal Python interpreter does not understand this `cd` command. You could use [IPython](http://ipython.org/), which does understand it, instead of the pure Python interpreter. However I assume that (1) you want the pure Python interpreter and (2) you don't want having to remember pressing these key combinations before and after each `cd` command. So, let's head to Step 3.

**Step 3: Translate and send the `cd` command automatically to the Python buffer**

We will re-alias Bash's builtin `cd` command to do a little more before actually changing the working directory in the current shell. Namely, whenever a user types `cd somewhere`,

1. We translate the command to Python
2. We use `xdotool` to simulate pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>
3. We use `xdotool` to simulate typing the translated command
4. We use `xdotool` to simulate pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>
5. We use `xdotool` to simulate pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

In this way, the translated command will be sent to the Python buffer. If you don't have it, install `xdotool`:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

The script that we want as an alias for `cd` will look something like this:

```
function cd_to_pybuf {
  xdotool type "#"
  xdotool key Ctrl+Insert
  xdotool type "os.chdir(\"$1\")"
  xdotool key Return
  xdotool key Ctrl+Delete
  cd "$1"
}
cd_to_pybuf
```

Explanation: When we alias `cd` to the above script, then whenever we type `cd somewhere`, Bash translates that to `OURSCRIPT somewhere`. Since our script ends with the function call `cd_to_pybuf`, it will actually call the function `cd_to_pybuf` with `somewhere` as argument (available as `$1` within the function; note that bash expansion would not work here, so we can't use something like `!*` to get at the arguments of the original command, and [`$BASH_COMMAND` is problematic too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513932/what-is-the-bash-command-variable-good-for)). This function performs exactly the steps enumerated above. On a sidenote, we also simulate typing `#` before we simulate pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>, because whatever we type after that will appear in *both* buffers, and Bash does not understand the `os.chdir` command, so with that `#` sign we make it into a comment for Bash. After the `xdotool` stuff, we also perform the actual `cd` command in the Bash buffer.

So now, we re-alias `cd` to that script, and test it:

[image]

It works! That `os.chdir("..")` command in the Python buffer was typed automatically. I didn't do it. All I did was type `cd ..` in the Bash buffer. You can see that the command `#os.chdir("..")` was also automatically typed into the Bash buffer, but since it's a comment it had no real effect.

To make this change permanent, put that alias into `~/.bashrc`, i.e., in your `~/.bashrc` add the line:

```
alias cd='function cd_to_pybuf { xdotool type "#"; xdotool key Ctrl+Insert; xdotool type "os.chdir(\"$1\")"; xdotool key Return; xdotool key Ctrl+Delete; cd "$1"; }; cd_to_pybuf'
```

And voilà! That was it.

**Bonus: an alias for `pwd`**

Sometimes you may want to check what the current working directory is in both buffers at once. We can use the very same technique as for `cd`, and re-alias `pwd`. The following command will do the trick, and you can also put it into your `~/.bashrc` if you like:

```
alias pwd='function pwd_to_pybuf { xdotool type "#"; xdotool key Ctrl+Insert; xdotool type "os.getcwd()"; xdotool key Return; xdotool key Ctrl+Delete; pwd; }; pwd_to_pybuf'
```

**What you will have to remember**

For this to work in the future, whenever you open up a split view with a Bash and a Python buffer, you will have to do two things:

1. Assign both buffers to the same group in Terminator
2. `import os` in your Python buffer

That's all.

**Troubleshooting**

This is not perfect. There are some minor problems:

1. It's a little ugly that this `#os.chdir` thingy gets printed to the Bash buffer also. It's really cosmetic, but you might consider doing something different, e.g., after you simulated typing the command and before simulating pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>, deactivate broadcasting temporarily and remove that command (e.g., simulate a lot of backspaces, or the sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) from the Bash buffer or whatever.
2. Some special arguments to `cd` will not work. Things like `cd -` (change to `$OLDPWD`), `cd ~` (change to `$HOME`), or `cd` (without arguments, also change to `$HOME`). Here also, the script could be improved to account for such special cases (check if `$1` is special, and translate appropriately). Such things should be a piece of cake from here, though.
3. Optional parameters to `cd`, such as, e.g., `cd -P somewhere`, will not work because the translation would be `os.chdir("-P")` here. You could use `$@` instead of `$1` to look at all arguments, and then do the appropriate thing.

Hope I could help :) It was an interesting challenge!

Comment: `HISTCONTROL=ignorespace` is a common setting. So, if you prefix the `#` with a space, it's quite likely that it won't get saved in the history.

Comment: This is totally awesome! I use IPython, but it's nice to know that you can also hack terminator & bash into working with the standard Python interpreter! http://imgur.com/JQ2X0PF

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to see it helped :)