# What is the $BASH_COMMAND variable good for?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

According to the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fCOMMAND), the environment variable `BASH_COMMAND` contains

> The command currently being executed or about to be executed, unless the shell is executing a command as the result of a trap, in which case it is the command executing at the time of the trap.

Taking that trap corner case aside, if I understand correctly this means that when I execute a command, the variable `BASH_COMMAND` contains that command. It's not absolutely clear whether that variable is unset after the command execution (i.e., is only avaialble *while* the command is running, but not after), though one might argue that since it is "the command *currently* being executed or *about to be* executed", it is not the command *that was just* executed.

But let's check:

```
$ set | grep BASH_COMMAND=
$
```

Empty. I would have expected to see `BASH_COMMAND='set | grep BASH_COMMAND='` or maybe just `BASH_COMMAND='set'`, but empty surprised me.

Let's try something else:

```
$ echo $BASH_COMMAND
echo $BASH_COMMAND
$
```

Well that makes sense. I execute the command `echo $BASH_COMMAND` and so the variable `BASH_COMMAND` contains the string `echo $BASH_COMMAND`. Why did it work this time, but not before?

Let's do the `set` thing again:

```
$ set | grep BASH_COMMAND=
BASH_COMMAND='echo $BASH_COMMAND'
$
```

So wait. It *was* set when I executed that `echo` command, and it *was not* unset afterwards. But when I executed `set` again, `BASH_COMMAND` *was not* set to the `set` command. No matter how often I execute the `set` command here, the result stays the same. So, is the variable set when executing `echo`, but not when executing `set`? Let's see.

```
$ echo Hello AskUbuntu
Hello AskUbuntu
$ set | grep BASH_COMMAND=
BASH_COMMAND='echo $BASH_COMMAND'
$
```

*What?* So the variable was set when I executed `echo $BASH_COMMAND`, but *not* when I executed `echo Hello AskUbuntu`? Where's the difference now? Is the variable only set when the current command itself actually forces the shell to evaluate the variable? Let's try something different. Maybe some external command this time, not a bash builtin, for a change.

```
$ /bin/echo $BASH_COMMAND
/bin/echo $BASH_COMMAND
$ set | grep BASH_COMMAND=
BASH_COMMAND='/bin/echo $BASH_COMMAND'
$
```

Hmm, ok... again, the variable was set. So is my current guess correct? Is the variable only set when it has to be evaluated? Why? *Why?* For performance reasons? Let's do one more try. We'll try to grep for `$BASH_COMMAND` in a file, and since `$BASH_COMMAND` should then contain a `grep` command, `grep` should grep for that `grep` command (i.e., for itself). so let's make an appropriate file:

```
$ echo -e "1 foo\n2 grep\n3 bar\n4 grep \$BASH_COMMAND tmp" > tmp
$ grep $BASH_COMMAND tmp
grep: $BASH_COMMAND: No such file or directory
tmp:2 grep                                      <-- here, the word "grep" is RED
tmp:4 grep $BASH_COMMAND tmp                    <-- here, the word "grep" is RED
tmp:2 grep                                      <-- here, the word "grep" is RED
tmp:4 grep $BASH_COMMAND tmp                    <-- here, the word "grep" is RED
$ set | grep BASH_COMMAND=
BASH_COMMAND='grep --color=auto $BASH_COMMAND tmp'
$
```

Ok, interesting. The command `grep $BASH_COMMAND tmp` got expanded to `grep grep $BASH_COMMAND tmp tmp` (the variable gets expanded just that once, of course), and so I grepped for `grep`, once in a file `$BASH_COMMAND` which doesn't exist, and twice in the file `tmp`.

**Q1:** Is my current assumption correct that:

- `BASH_COMMAND` is only set when a command tries to actually evaluate it; and
- it is *not* unset after execution of a command, even though the description may lead us to believe so?

**Q2:** If yes, why? Performance? If no, how else can the behavior in the above command sequence be explained?

**Q3:** Lastly, is there any scenario in which this variable could actually be meaningfully used? I was actually trying to use it within `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to analyze the command being executed (and do some stuff depending on that), but I can't, because as soon as, within my `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, I execute a command to look at the variable `$BASH_COMMAND`, the variable gets sets to that command. Even when I do `MYVARIABLE=$BASH_COMMAND` right at the beginning of my `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, then `MYVARIABLE` contains the string `MYVARIABLE=$BASH_COMMAND`, because an assignment is a command too. (This question is not about how I could obtain the current command within a `$PROMPT_COMMAND` execution. There are other ways, I know.)

It's a bit like with Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. Just by observing the variable, I change it.

Comment: Nice, but probably better suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ...there are real `bash` über-gurus there.

Comment: Well, is it possible to move it over there? Mods?

Comment: I am really not sure how to do it --- I suppose it's a Mod privilege. On the other hand I don't think flagging it is sensible --- let's see if someone acts on the close flag.

Comment: For the third point, [this](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/xterm-titles-with-bash/) is what you are searching for. Maybe based on that article you can find the answer for the first two points too.

Comment: @EliahKagan you're right --- it's on topic. Although I still think that probably trying this on unix.SE would be useful.

Comment: +1 confused the heck out of me, but it was fun to read!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answering to the third question: of course it can be used meaningfully in the way at Bash manual clearly hints – in a trap, e. g.:

```
$ trap 'echo ‘$BASH_COMMAND’ failed with error code $?' ERR
$ fgfdjsa
fgfdjsa: command not found
‘fgfdjsa’ failed with error code 127
$ cat /etc/fgfdjsa
cat: /etc/fgfdjsa: No such file or directory
‘cat /etc/fgfdjsa’ failed with error code 1
```

Comment: Ah, nice indeed. So would you say that a trap is the only context in which this variable makes sense? It sounded like a corner case in the manual: "The command being executed (...), *unless the shell is executing a command as the result of a trap,* ..."

Comment: After reading the articles linked in the answer by @DocSalvager, it is clear that `$BASH_COMMAND` can indeed be used meaningfully even in contexts other than a trap. Yet, the use you describe is probably the most typical and straight-forward. So your answer, and the one by DocSalvager, answer my **Q3** best, and this was the most important to me. As for Q1 and Q2, as indicated by @zwets, those things are undefined. It may be that `$BASH_COMMAND` is only given a value if accessed, for performance - or else some weird internal program conditions may lead to that behavior. Who knows?

Comment: On a sidenote, I discovered that you *can* force `$BASH_COMMAND` to be set always, by forcing evaluation of `$BASH_COMMAND` before each command. To do this we can use the DEBUG trap, which is executed before every single command (all of em). If we issue, e.g., `trap 'echo "$BASH_COMMAND" > /dev/null' DEBUG`, then `$BASH_COMMAND` will always be evaluated before each command (and assigned the value of that `$COMMAND`). So if I execute `set | grep BASH_COMMAND=` while that trap is active... what do you know? Now the output is `BASH_COMMAND=set`, as expected :)

Answer (score 6):

Now that Q3 has been answered (correctly, in my opinion: `BASH_COMMAND` is useful in traps and hardly anywhere else), let's give Q1 and Q2 a shot.

The answer to Q1 is: the correctness of your assumption is undecidable. The truth of neither of the bullet points can be established, as they ask about unspecified behaviour. By its specification, the value of `BASH_COMMAND` is set to the text of a command for the duration of the execution of that command. The spec does not state what its value must be in any other situation, i.e. when no command is being executed. It could have any value or none at all.

The answer to Q2 "If no, how else can the behavior in the above command sequence be explained?" then follows logically (if somewhat pedantically): it is explained by the fact that the value of `BASH_COMMAND` is undefined. Since its value is undefined, it can have any value, which is exactly what the sequence shows.

**Postscript**

There is one point where I think you're indeed hitting a soft spot in the spec. It's where you say:

> Even when I do MYVARIABLE=$BASH_COMMAND right at the beginning of my
>   $PROMPT_COMMAND, then MYVARIABLE contains the string
>   MYVARIABLE=$BASH_COMMAND, *because an assignment is a command too*.

The way I read the bash man page, the bit in italics is not true. The section `SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION` explains how first the variable assignments on the command line are set aside, and then

> If  no command name results [in other words, there were only variable
>   assignments], the variable assignments affect the current shell
>   environment.

This suggests to me that variable assignments are not commands (and therefore exempt from showing up in `BASH_COMMAND`), like in other programming languages. This would then also explain why there isn't a line `BASH_COMMAND=set` in the output of `set`, `set` essentially being a syntactic 'marker' for variable assignment.

OTOH, in the final paragraph of that section it says

> If there is a command name left after expansion, execution proceeds as
>   described below.  Otherwise, the **command** exits.

... which suggests otherwise, and variable assignments are commands too.

Comment: Just because some assumption can't be established does not mean it is incorrect. Einstein assumed that the speed of light is the same for any observer (at any speed) as one fundamental hypothesis for the theory of relativity; that cannot be established, yet this does not mean it's incorrect. The properties "can be established" and "is correct" are orthogonal. At best you could say "We don't know if it's correct, since it can't be established". Also, it *is* specified: it's the current command during execution. So if I type `set` I should see `BASH_COMMAND='set'` somewhere in that output, which

Comment: ...however is not the case. Even though that is *during execution of the `set` command*. Hence, according to specs it should work. So is it that the implementation does not faithfully obey the specs, or do I misunderstand the specs? Finding the answer to that question is kind of the purpose of Q1. +1 for your postscript :)

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa Good points. Fixed the answer accordingly, and added a remark about `set`.

Comment: It's possible that in the bash interpreter, `set` is not a "command". Just as `=` is not a "command". Processing of the text following/surrounding those tokens could have entirely different logic than the processing of a "command."

Comment: Good points from both of you. :) It may well be that `set` does not count as a "command". I wouldn't have thought that `$BASH_COMMAND` would turn out to be so underspecified in many circumstances. I guess at the very least we have established that the man page definitely *could* be clearer about it ;)

Answer (score 3):

**An inventive use for $BASH_COMMAND**

Recently found this [impressive use of $BASH_COMMAND](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910160505/https://simpletondigest.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/building-a-better-macro/) in implementing a macro-like functionality.

> This is the core trick of the alias and replaces the use of the DEBUG trap. If you read the part in the previous post about the DEBUG trap, you’ll recognize the $BASH_COMMAND variable. In that post I said that it was set to the text of the command before each call to the DEBUG trap. Well, it turns out it’s set before the execution of every command, DEBUG trap or no (e.g. run ‘echo “this command = $BASH_COMMAND”‘ to see what I’m talking about). By assigning it a variable (just for that line) we capture BASH_COMMAND at the outermost scope of the command, which will contain the entire command.

The author's [previous article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919090411/https://simpletondigest.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/fun-with-bash/) also provides some good background while implementing a technique using a DEBUG `trap`. The `trap` is eliminated in the improved version.

Comment: +1 I finally got around to read those two articles. Wow! What a read! Very enlightening. That guy is a bash *guru*! Kudos! This also answers my comment on Dmitry's answer on whether `$BASH_COMMAND` can be used meaningfully in a context other than a `trap`. And what a use that is! Using it to implement macro commands in bash -- who would have thought it possible? Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

A seemingly common use for the trap...debug is to improve the titles that appear in the windowlist (^A") when you are using "screen".

I was trying to make the "screen", "windowlist" more usable so I started to find articles referencing "trap...debug".

I found that the method using PROMPT_COMMAND to send the "null title sequence" did not work so well, so I reverted to the trap...debug method.

Here is how you do it:

1 Tell "screen" to look for the escape sequence (enable it) by putting "shelltitle '$|bash:'" into "$HOME/.screenrc".

2 Turn off the propagation of the debug trap into sub-shells. This is important, because if it is enabled, everything gets mucked up, use: "set +o functrace".

3 Send the title escape sequence for "screen" to interpret:
    trap 'printf "\ek$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) $(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd) ${BASH_COMMAND}\e\"' "DEBUG"

It's not perfect, but it helps, and you can use this method to put literally anything you like into the title

See the following "windowlist" (5 screens):

Num Name                                                                                                                                         Flags

1 bash:20161115232035 mcb@ken007:/home/mcb/ken007 RSYNCCMD="sudo rsync" myrsync.sh -R -r "${1}" "${BACKUPDIR}${2:+"/${2}"}"                        $
   2 bash:20161115230434 mcb@ken007:/home/mcb/ken007 ls --color=auto -la                                                                              $
   3 bash:20161115230504 mcb@ken007:/home/mcb/ken007 cat bin/psg.sh                                                                                   $
   4 bash:20161115222415 mcb@ken007:/home/mcb/ken007 ssh ken009                                                                                       $
   5 bash:20161115222450 mcb@ken007:/home/mcb/ken007 mycommoncleanup                                                                                  $